# Event Listeners - Equivalent for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firebug, chromium

I noticed Chromium has an interesting feature in the inspector/debugger: Event Listeners.[image: Chromium Inspector]

I haven't found the equivalent feature in Firefox Firebug. I saw a question from a couple years ago that said Firefox does not have an equivalent feature, but I'm wondering if there has been any update on this... Is there an addon yet for Firebug that lists listeners? Or, is there something about Firefox's implementation that makes this not practical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, this feature is natively in the firefox inspector, you not need firebug anymore :)
http://flailingmonkey.com/view-dom-events-in-firefox-developer-tools/

Comment: and it's more obvious and useful, telling where the actual jQuery-event was.

Comment: Yep, Chrome's native event listener couldn't watch the delegated events by jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

There's [Eventbug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug) which is Firebug extension.

Also, since [Firebug 1.12 beta 1](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2013/06/28/firebug-1-12-beta-1/), you can type `getEventListeners(element)` in the command line. However this needs specifying the exact element from which you want to retrieve event listeners.